# Adding textviews under buttons

Tags: java, android, layout

I've made a lay-out with 10 buttons. In those buttons i have icons, showing what the information inside is about. Under those buttons, I want to have a word to clearify that again.

I have no idea how to add textviews and place them exactly under those buttons. I have tried it from the lay-out, by just pressing Textview and put it under the buttons, but that way my entire lay-out goes downwards, and the position is not right under it, but slightly left of it. 
Hope someone can help me, every kind of help is appreciated.

This is my layout, the red circles are where I want the text to be.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6czT.png)

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/rkzafbeelding">


   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/logoversiejuni" />

 </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bezoektijdenbutton"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

          <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
            android:text="  Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/routebutton"
            android:text="Route" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/meningbutton"
            android:text="Uw mening" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/vriendenbutton"
            android:text="Word vriend" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/foldersbutton"
            android:text="Folders" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/specialistenbutton"
            android:text="Specialisten" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bwcbutton"
            android:text="Brandwond  encentrum" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/nieuwsbutton"
            android:text="Nieuws en Agenda" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/afspraakbutton"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better to use _GridView_

Comment: Might have been better. However, i'm working on this for ages, so I'm not gonna throw everything over and use gridview instead of what i have now. Must be a way to do it without it right?

Comment: The best thing would be getting rid of the Buttons. Use TextViews with a **compound drawable** (`drawableTop`, in this case). Make them clickable and display them in a GridView, as suggested by @PiyushGupta

Comment: you can add the text under the image in button, if you want :)

Comment: That's what I want to achieve.. How do i do that? Fransisco Melicias

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and check if it works?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"  --> you can change the size that you want
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1" --> you can change the size that you want
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: Getting this error on the last line: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_alignEnd' with value 'TheButtonInTheOtherSide').

Comment: also, this puts text next to the button on the right, not under it

Comment: you have to add the button in the alignEnd, i didnt know what was the name of the right button

Comment: android:layout_below= can be used only in RelativeLayouts

Comment: oh, awkward.. i'll try that

Comment: This still put's the text on the right side of the button, not under it

Comment: i give the code a ha I use and it worked for me, you can have a look to the code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e9ed3398dc0e01ec35290733bfbeccf8

and you can see thee result here: http://imgur.com/8pWKVd8

Answer (score 0):

You can try just using TextViews in your layout and add the icons to them as compound drawables using:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, yourIconDrawable, null, null);
```

This will put your drawable to the top of the text. To set the size of the drawable call setBounds(...) on it or use setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(...) on the TextView. You can also set the padding with setCompoundDrawablePadding(int padding).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this but this the not The right way to create this type of view the best way to create Using GridView**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="113dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title "/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, one of the most common ways is to use [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), and another common way is by using [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) which will give you the ability to predefine the views positions according to eachother(i.e which one is above the other), and following is a good example about how to use `RelativeLayout` to achieve your purpose:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Add   Button 1 -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <!-- Add  Text 1 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:text="text1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```